# Storing application wide instances

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I need to access the same instance of a class in many other classes inside my app, is it good practice to create a property in my app delegate containing this instance, then access the property from wherever I need it inside my app, using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.instance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. The best way is to use singleton classes: [link](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/)

Good luck!

Comment: Well, why is that a better alternative? The way I see it, the app delegate will live throughout the lifetime of the application and it already has a singleton available.

Comment: There's no real problem in using appdelegate for that sort of things, but it's not advisable. It's good practice to use appdelegate only to deal with requests from the OS

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, or you can use singletons as Heliem said.

However, you need to reference to the class of your delegate:

```
((MyAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).instance;
```